# SassError: Undefined variable in next js

Tags: css, webpack, next.js, sass, bootstrap-5

```
SassError: Undefined variable.
   ╷
55 │     "primary": $primary-text-emphasis-dark,
   │                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_maps.scss 55:16  @import
  styles/theme/_utilities.scss 7:9              @import
  styles/theme.scss 29:9                        root stylesheet
```

I'm trying to integrate the dashui admin template into my Next.js application. I cloned the code from GitHub, and when I run it independently, everything works perfectly. However, when I attempt to load the template into my application, I encounter a Sass error. The strange thing is that I haven't made any changes to the code, and I'm using the exact same dependencies as the original clone.

I want to troubleshoot this issue, but I'm unsure where to begin since the code seems to be running fine. I don't want to modify the import order as I believe it is correct. Could you please assist me in understanding why I'm getting this Sass error and provide guidance on how to resolve it?

Thank you in advance for your help!

node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_maps.scss file

```
@if $enable-dark-mode {
  // scss-docs-start theme-text-dark-map
  $theme-colors-text-dark: (
    "primary": $primary-text-emphasis-dark,
    "secondary": $secondary-text-emphasis-dark,
    "success": $success-text-emphasis-dark,
    "info": $info-text-emphasis-dark,
    "warning": $warning-text-emphasis-dark,
    "danger": $danger-text-emphasis-dark,
    "light": $light-text-emphasis-dark,
    "dark": $dark-text-emphasis-dark,
  ) !default;
  // scss-docs-end theme-text-dark-map

  // scss-docs-start theme-bg-subtle-dark-map
  $theme-colors-bg-subtle-dark: (
    "primary": $primary-bg-subtle-dark,
    "secondary": $secondary-bg-subtle-dark,
    "success": $success-bg-subtle-dark,
    "info": $info-bg-subtle-dark,
    "warning": $warning-bg-subtle-dark,
    "danger": $danger-bg-subtle-dark,
    "light": $light-bg-subtle-dark,
    "dark": $dark-bg-subtle-dark,
  ) !default;
```

_utilities.scss

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities";
```

theme.scss

```
// Inter Fonts
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap");

// Font Awesome
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css");

// Feathers CSS for Before Icon
@import url("/fonts/feather-icons/feather.css");

// Bootstrap functions
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";

// User Variables
@import "user-variables";

// theme variables
@import "theme/variables";

//utilities
@import "theme/utilities";

// Bootstrap
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

// Theme
@import "theme/theme";

// User
@import "user";
```

segment of the variables.scss

```
$white: #fff !default;
$gray-100: #f1f5f9 !default;
$gray-200: #f4f6f8 !default;
$gray-300: #dfe3e8 !default;
$gray-400: #c4cdd5 !default;
$gray-500: #919eab !default;
$gray-600: #637381 !default;
$gray-700: #454f5b !default;
$gray-800: #212b36 !default;
$gray-900: #161c24 !default;
$black: #000 !default;
$red: #dc3545 !default;
$orange: #fd7e14 !default;
$yellow: #f59e0b !default;
$green: #198754 !default;
$teal: #20c997 !default;
$cyan: #0ea5e9 !default;
$primary: #624bff !default;
$secondary: $gray-600 !default;
$success: $green !default;
$info: $cyan !default;
$warning: $yellow !default;
$danger: $red !default;
$light: $gray-100 !default;
$dark: $gray-800 !default;

// Light color
$light-primary: #e0dcfe !default; // NEW
$light-secondary: #e9ecef !default; // NEW
$light-success: #eaf6ec !default; // NEW
$light-danger: #fbebec !default; // NEW
$light-warning: #fff3cd !default; // NEW
$light-info: #e7fafe !default; // NEW
$light-dark: #d1cfd8 !default; // NEW

// Dark color
$dark-primary: #593cc1 !default; // NEW
$dark-secondary: #5c596d !default; // NEW
$dark-success: #139a74 !default; // NEW
$dark-danger: #ae302e !default; // NEW
$dark-warning: #c28135 !default; // NEW
$dark-info: #51a0c2 !default; // NEW

$theme-colors: () !default;
$theme-colors: (
    "primary": $primary,
    "secondary": $secondary,
    "success": $success,
    "info": $info,
    "warning": $warning,
    "danger": $danger,
    "light": $light,
    "dark": $dark,
    "white": $white,
    "light-primary": $light-primary,
    "light-danger": $light-danger,
    "light-info": $light-info,
    "light-warning": $light-warning,
    "light-secondary": $light-secondary,
    "light-success": $light-success,
    "light-dark": $light-dark,
    "dark-primary": $dark-primary,
    "dark-warning": $dark-warning,
    "dark-info": $dark-info,
    "dark-danger": $dark-danger,
    "dark-success": $dark-success,
    "dark-secondary": $dark-secondary,
);
```

Comment: Could you add the scss/variables file ?

Comment: Done,the file is too long I have added a section I think is relevant to the question.

Comment: The variable doesn't seems to have been declared. Is $primary-text-emphasis-dark present / declared in another file ?